# Breaking up a large PHP object used to abstract the database. Best practices?

Tags: php, object-oriented, refactoring, mysql

Two years ago it was thought a single object with functions such as `$database->get_user_from_id($ID)` would be a good idea. The functions return objects (not arrays), and the front-end code never worries about the database.

This was great, until we started growing the database. There's now 30+ tables, and around 150 functions in the database object. It's getting impractical and unmanageable and I'm going to be breaking it up.

What is a good solution to this problem? The project is large, so there's a limit to the extent I can change things.

My current plan is to extend the current object for each table, then have the database object contain these. So, the above example would turn into (assume "user" is a table) `$database->user->get_user_from_id($ID)`. Instead of one large file, we would have a file for every table.

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM?

Comment: @Songo He is, just not a very efficient one. What OP is describing is an (extremely crude) custom implementation of an Active Record.

Comment: Alas there's a time limit on getting this sorted. To convert the project to using a proper ORM, whilst ideal, would be too time consuming.  There's around 600 references to this database object in the code, and only one programmer to sort it. Unless I'm missing a trick and there's a smart way to do it?

Comment: You might switch a propre ORM (you will save lots ot time in the future!) and might write some proxy function to handle the migration. Then, start to use (for new and every time you modify an existing functionnality) the ORM functions once the proxy where written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, forget about tables.  Tables are storage.  Think about your classes instead.  Often classes can be saved in a single table, but not always.  So dont think of them as interchangable.  They are *very* different things.

What you want to do is move the database queries into your classes.  Keep the database abstraction layer - just use it to execute queries that are passed into it.

So, instead of this:

```
$u = $database->user->get_user_from_id($ID);
```

do this:

```
$u = new User( $ID);
```

The constructor of the User class would handle loading the user from the db.

```
class User
{
   __construct( $id)
   {
      global $database;

      $database->Query( "select name, etc... from users where id = ?", $id);
      //load the object from query result
   }
}
```

You then extend it so that it can do other tasks:

```
$u = new User( $ID);
$u->Email = "newemail@some.com";
$u->Save();
```

Where Save() might be

```
function Save()
{
   global $database;  //there are other ways to do this, but you get the idea


   $database->query("update users set ......");

}
```

Now you actually have classes doing what they should be doing - the User class worries about users.  The Database class worries about the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend to you is to make a database class that knows how to run commands aganst the database and return things in a way you like make it expandable and easy to work with so you can do easy things like the following.

```
$table('user')->select('*')->where('user_id', 1234, '=')->exec();
```

that will make it easy to expand that is not the best example but look into active record like suggested, also the one in code igniter is pretty good.

Then extend that class will all the tables that you need to work with. or group them byh the type of call that should make it easy for you to be able to keep everything nice and up to date and have smaller classes.